# Slowed/smoothed touch pad movement; 2022 dell xps 15; Arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, touchpad, dell-xps

After using my computer for a while, the touch pad starts to become slow. It almost becomes smooth when moving slowly.

Please tell me what resources you all would need to help me diagnose this issue.

Comment: Update the driver if you can. That  is what I do. Run Dell hardware diagnostics also.

Comment: @John I really can't figure out how to update the driver while in arch linux--or even what updates to install.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done it already, I believe you can run a `sudo pacman -Suy` to update the entire system via the arch linux package manager, which includes drivers installed via pacman (which I think are most drivers needed for daily usage). This will update everything though, so make sure you are ready for that, like doing any necessary backups etc. If you installed the touchpad driver outside of pacman, I think you need to download and install the update yourself, following instructions that should hopefully be listed where you downloaded the driver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Definitely had to update the drivers; I still haven't found a solution, but this page was a good start https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/618#note_1368877; toupad drivers are not managed under pacman